# Can RewriteRule without [F] guaranty 100% no access to original files?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, security, mod-rewrite

How to keep directory `/sec` content secure and inaccessible while using `RewriteRule` with root `index.php`? Would this guaranty 100% security - denied access to `/sec` content?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} sec($|/)
RewriteRule ^(*)$ index.php [L]
```

Unfortunately ordinary approach to deny access returns HTTP "403 Forbidden" and disallows `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^sec($|/) - [F]
```

or in `/sec`:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

Can `RewriteRule` without `[F]` cover "deny access to original files in `/sec`"? Any better approach on keeping `index.php` rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

While this rule that you have shown:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} sec($|/)
RewriteRule ^(*)$ index.php [L]
```

may work for now but have 2 potential issues:

1. Wrong regex, as it will also block `/sector`
2. If some developer decides to create a `/sec/.htaccess` someday above rule will be **totally ignored**.

Safest is to have this rule in `/sec/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

Also keep directory slash on (by default on) in root .htaccess:

```
DirectorySlash On
```

Comment: I want `/sec` to be rewritten by `index.php` too. The main question is - will `/sec` original files access be 100% denied? Is there any way to apply `[F]` and keep `index.php` rewrite?

Comment: Yes `/sec` will also be written to `/index.php` if you don't turn off `DirectorySlash` in root htaccess (which must be always on anyway for security reasons). Yes it will behave exactly like you want i.e. `F` and `/index.php` combo